# Redis sorted set wrong score

Tags: redis

Let's try this.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aaa 999999999999991.1 one
(integer) 0
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zscore aaa one
"999999999999991.12"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aaa 999999999999991.2 one
(integer) 0
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zscore aaa one
"999999999999991.25"
```

Any solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your redis is using IEEE 754 64-bit numbers.

When you try to represent 999999999999991.1 in a 64-bit floating-point register, the closest hex representation is 430c6bf52633ffb9.  The *exact* decimal representation for that is 999999999999991.125 which your redis-cli is displaying as 999999999999991.12.

Similarly when you enter 999999999999991.2 the closest bit pattern found is 430c6bf52633ffba, which is exactly 999999999999991.25 -- which your redis-cli is able to show.

This loss-of-precision because of fixed register size shows up in nearly every system,  Redis is no exception.